# Webfont using @font-face stopped working

Tags: css, font-face

I`ve been using webfonts on my website, using @font-face and it stopped working after some browser updates, now it doesn`t really work on Chrome or Firefox (the two main browsers my users use).
I tried a couple of different things but none of them made it work again. Does anyone have any idea of what could have happened?

My website is [http://goronah.blog.br/](http://goronah.blog.br)

The link for the CSS is: http://www.goronah.blog.br/wp-content/themes/goronahresponsive/style.css

The @font-face is:

```
@font-face{
    font-family:Bebas Neue;
    src: url('BebasNeue.otf');
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:normal;
}
```

and a common use:

```
h2 {
    font-size:2.4em;
    font-family:"Bebas Neue";
    font-weight:normal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Chrome DevTools shows the following error regarding the font:

> Font from origin 'http://www.goronah.blog.br' has been blocked from
>   loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://goronah.blog.br' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Basically due to security reasons the browser won't download the font as it comes from another (sub)domain `www.goronah.blog.br` than your site `goronah.blog.br`. I noticed that the first simply redirects to the latter, so I assume it's simply an alias and all content is available from both url's.

The easiest way to solve this is to remove the `www.` part from the link to your stylesheet.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.goronah.blog.br/wp-content/themes/goronahresponsive/style.css" />
```

into

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://goronah.blog.br/wp-content/themes/goronahresponsive/style.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

To make sure you cover all browsers with your font, you need to specifiy different font-types.

You need a:

- WOFF or WOFF2 (Woff2 had better rendering)
- SVG
- EOT
- TTF or OTF

To generate these fonts, you can use a webfont-generator like http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator.

If you have all the required font-types, you can include them like this (see comments in code for broswer support):

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Bebas Neue';
  src: url('BebasNeue.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('BebasNeue.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('BebasNeue.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('BebasNeue.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('BebasNeue.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('BebasNeue.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
  font-style:normal;
  font-weight:normal;
}
```